# WPF DataGrid: how to know if ValidationTemplate is enabled

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application, I have a view with an editable datagrid and a viewmodel. This is an existing codebase, and a problem arises: there are fields in the viewmodel that raises exceptions but those fields are not in the view. A refactor is necessary, but for now we need to implement a visual clue (red border around the row) for the user as a quick fix.

From the viewmodel, I raise an event that a validation took place, and in the code-behind, I want to check in the datagridrow if the ValidationErrorTemplate is enabled.

As the elements added by the ValidationErrorTemplate are added as AdornerLayer outside of the datagridrows, it seems that I have no clue to which datagridrow this is coupled?

I have not much code to show, just that I get to the correct datagridrow for which viewmodel a validation took place:

```
private void OnValidationEvent(ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = BoekingDatagrid.GetDataGridRow(e.ID);
    if (e.HasErrors)
    {
        if (errorBorder == null)
        {
            row.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);

            var vm = row.DataContext as ItemBaseViewModel;
            LogValidationErrors(vm, UserContext);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```

Every column has the following xaml, with a Validation.ErrorTemplate:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" 
        CanUserResize="False" 
        SortMemberPath ="Name"
        Width="130"
        MinWidth="130">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ViewMode, Converter={StaticResource ViewModeToBoolean}, ConverterParameter=name}"  
                Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ErrorTemplate2_Grid}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

ErrorTemplate2_Grid adds a red border and tooltip to the cell.

In Visual Live Tree, you can see that the rows and the error visuals, but they are not nested:

[image: Visual Live Tree]

The question is: how can I find out if there are visual error elements added to the datagridrow, when the viewmodel is invalid?

Comment: You can run your application and see whether it is applied or not? Programmatically you can check the property HasErrors. Visual Live Tree always shows adorners in a separate visual tree.

Comment: @sa.he On which object do I have to find the HasErrors property?

Comment: Is 'OnValidationEvent' an attempt to visualize validation errors? This method already uses a HasErrors property. Normally you do not need any events, but the bound model objects implement INotifyDataErrorInfo which contains the HasErrors property amongst others. Very compact: WPF Binding first queries the HasErrors property. If that is true, it calls GetErrors("your property name"). If that returns an error string, the ValidationErrorTemplate is applied.

Comment: Or if you want you could use `ValidationRule`, then you would know if it was applied or not. INotifyDataErrorInfo is a left over from `WinFroms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what BindingGroup exactly does, but the databound rows does have there own BindingGroups with only the databindings of the controls in the row. And a very convenient property: HasValidationError

```
private void OnValidationEvent(ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    var row = BoekingDatagrid.GetDataGridRow();

    if (row != null)
    {
        if (e.HasErrors)
        {
            if (!row.BindingGroup.HasValidationError)
            {
                row.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            }
            else
            {
                row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answered for mine and others future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Validation in WPF is typically done using the interface `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. There are other ways too, but the ViewModel raising an event that the View handles isn't typically one of them. A very simplified model class could look like this:

```
public class Model : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public Model(int myInt, string myString)
    {
        MyInt = myInt;
        MyString = myString;
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return MyInt == 88 || MyString == "foo";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public int MyInt
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { }
    }

    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (propertyName == nameof(MyInt) && MyInt == 88)
                return new string[] { "MyInt must not be 88" };

            if (propertyName == nameof(MyString) && MyString == "foo")
                return new string[] { "MyString must not be 'foo'" };

            return new string[0];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new string[] { "Exception" };
        }
    }
}
```

A quick and diry window could look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Models = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model(1,"hello"),
            new Model(1,"foo"),
            new Model(88,"hello"),
            new Model(2,"world"),
        };

        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

whereas the XAML just contains `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" />`
A red rectangle in case of an error is default. Just apply your custom template and do not set any ValidationErrorTemplate.

[image: Screenshot of demo code]

Comment: All this is already in place. I want to know the if there is a "hidden" validation error.

Comment: An Exception in getter / HasErrors and GetErrors actually does not show the validation template. I added try-catch to the sample code.